# angular material mat-table generate table dynamically and the table header values should be defined by the user with a input box

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

angular material mat-table generate table dynamically and the table header values should be defined by the user with a input box

my exact requirement is :

user will enter the values inside the input box
one by one for e.g: name,age,dob and clicking on the submit button should have to create a table
with the following header names.

here is the code

```
tableGeneratorForm.html
 <form [formGroup]="field">
  <mat-form-field class="" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Use Comma to separate values" formControlName="label">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="pushValue()">Add</button>

<button mat-button>Action</button>
<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width:'100%';">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>

tableGeneratorForm.ts;

import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: "app-table-generator-form",
  templateUrl: "./table-generator-form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./table-generator-form.component.scss"],
})
export class TableGeneratorFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  arr: FormArray;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      arr: fb.array([this.storeValue]),
    });
  }

  field = this.fb.group({
    label: [],
  });

  tabledisplay = false;

  storeValue: any[] = [];

  controlsType: any;
  pushValue() {this.storeValue.push(this.getValue);console.log(this.storeValue);
    this.field.reset();this.tabledisplay = true;}
  get getValue() {
    let label = this.field.get("label").value;
    return label;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  display!: [];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ["one"];

  columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns;

  data: [];
}
```

i am able to get the user entered values into an array but i am unable to pass the storevalue (which has the user entered values for the table header) to the displayedColumns

can anyone kindly help out to solve this issue

here is the stackblitz of the above code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qhbmuc
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qhbmuc)

Comment: just equal the displayColumns to `this.field.value.label.split(',')` (displayColumns must be an array)